# I can't run rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails

```
$bundle exec rspec spec/
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I'm totally new to Rails and trying to read the tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec:TDD

However, when I try to run rspect, I get that error.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT** My `Gemfile`

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.3'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.8.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.8.1'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: Tried that:
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
MoonBookPro:sample_app shamoon$

Comment: Try `bundle exec rspec spec`.

Comment: Same

MoonBookPro:sample_app shamoon$ bundle exec rspec spec
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add

```
gem "rake", '0.9.2.2'
```

to your gemfile (under gem 'rails' or what so ever..).

Run `bundle install` afterwards

Then run `bundle exec rspec spec` at last.

Will this work for you? If not, any error messages?
If there are error messages please type `rake -V` and `bundle exec rake -V` in your console and share us the versions!

Comment: I added it. Same results. I ran `bundle install` then `bundle exec rspec spec` and same message

Comment: I have RVM installed if that matters

Comment: Run `bundle exec rake -V`

Do you have the correct rvm gemset selected?

Comment: if running `bundle exec rake -V` wont show version 0.9.2.2 you might want to try executing  `bundle update rake`

Comment: `MoonBookPro:sample_app shamoon$ bundle exec rake -v
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb
..

Finished in 0.06803 seconds
2 examples, 0 failures
MoonBookPro:sample_app shamoon$ `

This is the wrong version.. interesting. How do I fix?

Comment: Sorry my command was written wrong. You should execute `bundle exec rake -V` (Capital V ) ...

Comment: `MoonBookPro:sample_app shamoon$ bundle exec rake -V
rake, version 0.9.2.2`

Comment: Reinstalled RVM and Ruby 1.9. Works

Comment: Was about to suggest that, using ruby 1.9.2 with a specific bundle file. A hint is make a gemset for your project.. http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/